# phpinfo page saprfc module not shown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, saprfc

i have installed saprfc-1.4.1 on linux 4.0.4-x86_64 (ubuntu14) machine.

PHP Version : PHP 5.6.11

Steps Completed

- Downloaded rfcsdk 7.20 and uploaded in /usr/local/rfcsdk
- Uploaded  librfccm.so patch in rfcsdk/lib
- Extracted saprfc-1.4.1 in my root directory
- edited file saprfc-1.4.1/saprfc.c (on line no.47 changed function_entry to zend_function_entry )
- in saprfc-1.4.1 executed following command

  - phpize
  - ./configure
  - make
  - make install
- added extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/saprfc.so in php.ini file
- sudo service apache2 restart

After doing these all steps in phpinfo page saprfc module was not shown.

In **Additional .ini files parsed** section in phpinfo page saprfc.ini path was mentioned

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-saprfc.ini
```

when i checked /var/log/apache2/error.log file i got following error

```
caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: saprfc: Unable to initialize module\nModule
compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    
compiled with module API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: saprfc: Unable to initialize module\nModule
compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module
API=20121212\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution to this issue.

There were 2 PHP installed php 5.5.9 and 5.6.11.

run **which php** (to find php is being used)
it returned me    */usr/bin/*

Executed following command in saprfc :

```
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
make
make test
make install
```

add extension (extension=saprfc.so) in php.ini file

restart apache

sudo service apache2 restart